# Expects an Object or Array value in Vue [ Warn ]

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I've been running into a warning that I want to hide/fix. I read you can hide warnings using `Vue.config.ignoredElements`, and have added the code below in my `main.js` file:

```js
Vue.config.ignoredElements = [
  'slot v-bind without argument expects an Object',
  'Expected Object, got Array',
  'v-bind without argument expects an Object or Array value'
  ]
```

Is there a specific option I need to add? or a better way to fix this problem?

This issue might be related: https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/6677

Answer (score 3):

I think you've misunderstood. `ignoredElements` solves a very specific problem.

Typically when Vue is rendering it comes across 3 types of element:

1. HTML elements, such as `<div>`.
2. Special Vue elements, such as `<template>` or `<slot>`.
3. Components, such as `<v-select>`.

Vue has a list of HTML elements hard-coded so that it can identify the first group. See:

https://github.com/vuejs/vue/blob/399b53661b167e678e1c740ce788ff6699096734/src/platforms/web/util/element.js#L11

If it comes across an element with a name it doesn't recognise it will log an error. Most of the time that's fine but occasionally you might need Vue to treat an unknown element just like a plain HTML element. That can be achieved by adding it to `ignoredElements`. See https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#ignoredElements for more details.

It is not used to suppress warning messages more generally.

You mentioned three messages:

1. slot v-bind without argument expects an Object
2. Expected Object, got Array
3. v-bind without argument expects an Object or Array value

In all cases these mean that there's a bug in your code. You shouldn't be trying to suppress these warnings, you should be fixing the bugs.